# Using DFS to print out a Tree in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, binary-tree

I am working on Trees and wanted to print out the tree in a Stack

Here's what I got so far.

```
class TreeNode<T>(var key: T,){
    var left: TreeNode<T>? = null
    var right: TreeNode<T>? = null
}

fun depthFirstValues(root: TreeNode<Char>){
    val stack = mutableListOf(root)
    while (stack.size > 0){
       val current = stack.removeFirst()
//        println(current.key)

        if(current.right!!.equals(true)) stack.add(current.right!!)
        if (current.left!!.equals(true)) stack.add(current.left!!)


    }
    println(stack)
}

fun buildTree(): TreeNode<Char>{
    val a = TreeNode('a')
    val b = TreeNode('b')
    val c = TreeNode('c')
    val d = TreeNode('d')
    val e = TreeNode('e')
    val f = TreeNode('f')


    a.left = b
    a.right = c
    b.left = d
    b.right = e
    c.right = f

    return a
}
```

I got an emptyList as the return value. I have been tinkering with it throughout the day, but not sure how to get it to work. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three major problems with your code.

- You need an extra collection to store the results of the depth-first traversal, if you want to store the entire traversal in a collection, and print it out at the end.

  You can't just use the same stack as the one you use to implement the traversal, because that stack is *guaranteed* to be empty at the end of the algorithm, as indicated by the condition on the while loop - `stack.size == 0`.
- You are not actually using `stack` like a stack. You are removing elements from its front (`removeFirst`), but adding to its end (`add`), like a queue. To use it like a stack, you should add to/remove from the *same* end of the list.
- You are not checking nulls correctly. `current.right!!.equals(true)` is false if `current.right` is not null, and will throw an exception if it is null - doesn't make much sense at all, does it?

Fixing these issues, we have:

```
fun depthFirstValues(root: TreeNode<Char>){
    val stack = mutableListOf(root)
    val result = mutableListOf<Char>()
    while (stack.isNotEmpty()){
        val current = stack.removeLast()
        current.left?.apply(stack::add)
        current.right?.apply(stack::add)
        result.add(current.key) // could also get rid of "result" and just println(current.key) here
    }
    println(result)
}
```

When applied to your tree, it prints `[a, c, f, b, e, d]`.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely interpreted the question wrong. I was on my computer all day and just completely missed it.